# YII - Sort a dataProvider with an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, yii

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [54995] => Array
        (
            [id] => 54995
            [create_time] => 2012-02-02 20:09:00
        )
    [57349] => Array
        (
            [id] => 57349
            [create_time] => 2012-02-09 23:26:00
        )
    [63565] => Array
        (
            [id] => 63565
            [create_time] => 2013-10-26 15:55:30
        )
    [63566] => Array
        (
            [id] => 63566
            [create_time] => 2013-10-26 15:56:32
        )
)
```

and a dataProvider that sorted by id.

I will sort dataProvider with this array's create_time.

Array ids is equals with posts id in dataProvider.

can I do this?

## **Edit:**

I have ***Link*** and ***Tag*** model. I use dataProvider for link but create time stored in tag table.

Tag fields:

- id
- title
- link_id
- create_time

Link fields:

- id
- title

Link dataProvider generator:

```
$pCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
$pCriteria->condition = 'status=:p1';
$pCriteria->params = array(':p1' => Lookup::STATUS_PUBLISHED_ALL);
$pCriteria->addInCondition('id', $pishnahadIds);
$pLinks = Link::model()->findAll($pCriteria);
```

And I have no relation for some reasons.

Comment: can you provide the code you are using to generate the dataprovider, this may be a simple as adding a criteria into your dataprovider

Comment: @JonPaulH thanks, I added more information

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want the returned data to be ordered by create_time instead of id?
For that simply use the [CDbCriteria order property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#order-detail).

```
$pCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
// ...
$pCriteria->with = array('tag'); // Only works with properly setup relationships, otherwise use $pCriteria->join = '...';
$pCriteria->order = 'tag.create_time ASC'; // or DESC, whatever you need
$pLinks = Link::model()->findAll($pCriteria);
```

To fix the relationship information you need to specify the relations in each model. Take a look at [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr). That should hopefully give you a few pointers. In short each model has a `relations()` function that returns an array describing the relationships it has to other models.

**Edit**

As apparently my approach is wrong … could you clarify the description of your problem a little, chalist? Right now I think you want the results of the `Link::model()->findAll()` operation to be sorted by `create_time`. Also where does the original array at the top come from?

**Edit 2**

Okay, so Links and Tags share a 1:1 relationship and you want Link output sorted by the corresponding Tag's creation time? Does the array you describe have to be manually created? Do you need it outside the proposed sorting of Links?

Comment: Attend to title and description dude

Comment: array's id is in link table and create time is in tag table. I create array manually